# UITextField not getting displayed in View

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I'm programatically creating a `UITextField`, called `nameTextField` in my `viewDidLoad` something like this:

```
var nameTextField = UITextField() 
nameTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 30, height: 20))
nameTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
nameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
nameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
nameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
nameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
nameTextField.placeholder = "Enter Your Full Name"
nameTextField.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(nameTextField)
```

I'm not seeing this my view, what mistake Am I making? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show some code of the view?

Comment: Try printing the textfield frame.

Comment: I ran the code, and I can see the UITextField

Comment: check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your view background color is `white` so that reason it wont show change the background color

```
nameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

**choice 2**

if your VC is embed with **navigation controller** , change the `Y frame` and check

```
nameTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 90, width: 30, height: 20))
```

as well as change the bg color

```
nameTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to take into consideration the navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where you want the text field to show up relative to the main view of your view controller.  For instance this would work: `nameTextField.center = self.view.center`